# Passing information to @With annotation play framework for user authorization

Tags: java, annotations, playframework-2.0, authorization

I am writing an application in play 2.4, before an action is carried out I want to ensure that a user has permission to perform the action.

I am able to retrieve the current user using information in the request header but it would be useful if the actions name could be passed like this for example.

```
@With(Authorization.class , action="create_account")
public static Result createAccount(){
   return ok("Account created");
}
```

and then authorization could do something like this.

```
public class Authorization extends Action.Simple{
   @Override
   public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable{
      if(action == "zoom")
         throw new UnauthorizedExcption("You can't do that!");
      else
           return delegate.call(context);
   }
```

So essentially my problem is that I need to pass data to the Authorization class. Any solutions to this type of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom annotation yourself which accepts a parameter:

```
@With(Authorization.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Auth {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Annotate your controller method as follows:

```
@Auth("create-account")
public static Result createAccount(){
   return ok("Account created");
}
```

To retrieve the value from annotation, make `Authorization` class extend `Action<Auth>`:

```
public class Authorization extends Action<Auth> {
    String value = configuration.value();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar by passing data between Sessions. Take a look at the following links! Hope this helps! :)

- [Play framework 2: Passing java objects between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441061/play-framework-2-passing-java-objects-between-controllers)
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaSessionFlash